# What are some advanced features you can add to any generic application?

Tags: java, p2p, file-sharing

I've almost finished my Java p2p file sharing application and given that it's pretty simple, I would like to add some things to it. Some modules or something like that. As you may notice I'm a newbie and still learning, so I haven't quite figured out all the possibilities.

Can you please recommend me anything you would think I could use but that doesn't require too much time to get around.

Thanks.
BTW I'm aware some of you could say my question is not precise, but I wish I could ask it better :)

Comment: Changing the word 'sophisticated' might keep this question open longer. Sophisticated is a very subjective word and you could get better response by maybe rephrasing it like "What are some advanced features you can add to any generic application?" (off-the-cuff example)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is the user base of your application? If people other than you are using it, try to get feedback on the application, issues, etc. If you are still trying to get your application up to the point where other people will want to use it, try some of the following:

- The single biggest thing you can do
  is probably to improve the GUI. Take
  a look here for some resources on GUI
  design:
  [Why is good UI design so hard for some Developers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/514083/why-is-good-ui-design-so-hard-for-some-developers)
- Make an installer for
  your software that adds start menu icons for the application and an uninstaller. Look here to get started: [Java Application Installers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/184060/java-application-installers)
- Do compatibility testing with different OS/Java versions. Focus on stability and preventing application crashes.

Comment: It's a simple file sharing application that works inside the LAN, still not getting it to work over the internet.
I like your points and examples, thank you, I'll be sure to check it.

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question and trying to help out.

Answer (score 4):

Add what testing shows people need, not what you think would be gee-whiz.

Comment: +1: "Modules" aren't something you just add.  You don't fling oregano into everything you cook; you don't drive in reverse just to show that you can use all the gears in the car.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on Jherico's answer, make sure that you track everything that a user does so that you are able to compare meaningful data when you change something.

The more you track and the more you test the better your application can get. If you're not recording any usage data then any changes you do make are just shots in the dark and you'll never know if you are actually affecting the areas you want.

Answer (score 1):

Implement Google-like single-input-field search over all data.

This is sometimes hard to do (since many applications store their data in a RDBMS and those are not ideally suited for this search approach), but it often makes navigating your UI much, much easier for the user.

So instead of filling in a "firstname" field and a "name field" and a "city" field, the user simply types "John Doe New York" into a single field and gets the result he expects.

[Lucene](http://lucene.apache.org/java/docs/)/[Lucene.Net](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/) are one way to implement such a feature. I'm sure there are similar libraries for other languages.

Answer (score 0):

Make it open source and let more people use it for free.. That helps you get reviews and new requirements from real users and help building a better software. Also making it open source will help you get new experienced developers working for the tool and you can learn more working with them.

Comment: It's already an open source, free for everyone.
It would require a lot of work to even consider making it commercialy valuable.

Answer (score 0):

This will probably be closed soon, but here are some easy things to add to make it looks more polished:

- Splash Screen
- Notification Icon (and hide the window)
- use native look and feel

Comment: Splash screens are a curse. As a user, why would I want to be delayed while your application loads and displays some crass splash screen I have no interest in seeing?

Comment: @Winston: I agree: the time spent to make a good splash screen is much better used when you speed up startup time by 1-2 seconds.

Comment: Adding a splash screen takes 15 minutes.  Speeding up startup time might take weeks.  Further, even if you can speed it up by 2 seconds, there still might be 5 other seconds that it is starting up.   Sometimes you just can't get around some startup time.

Answer (score 0):

> "Perfection is achieved, not when there
>   is nothing more to add, but when there
>   is nothing left to take away." --  Antoine de Saint-Exupéry

Adding features for the sake of having more features is just about the worst thing you can do to an application. Look at the recent move of Google: hiding everything but the logo, the search box and two buttons. That's the direction you should try taking, not deliberate [feature creep](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_creep).